Python Dash: add a point to plot that follows the plot according to x-value given
I want to create a plot in Plotly with 2 features:

It is a scatterplot/lineplot that plots a list of y vs list of x variables.
It has a 2nd dot whose x-value is controlled by a slider (range is constrained to x variables list). This dot will follow the plot in 1.

I do not know how to implement the 2nd feature.
This is my code. The first trace handles the 1st plot, the second trace should handle the 2nd dot:
# library imports
import dash
from dash import html, Input, Output, dcc
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import pandas as pd

# data
df = pd.DataFrame(
    data = {
        "varA": [1.5, 2.3, 3.1, 4.4954],
        "varB": [6.1232, 4.4343, 8.432, 5.39],
    }
)
# app info
style_sheets = [
    dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP
]
app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=style_sheets)
app.layout = html.Div(
    [
        dcc.Graph("graph"),
        dcc.Slider(
            min = min(df["varA"].tolist()),
            max = max(df["varA"].tolist()),
            value = 0,
            id="slider"
        )
    ]
)

# Callback
@app.callback(
    Output("graph", "figure"),
    [Input("slider", "value")]
)
def create_graph(slider_input):
    fig = go.Figure()
    fig.add_trace(
        go.Scatter(
            x=df["varA"],
            y=df["varB"],
            mode='lines+markers',  # add markers
            marker=dict(size=10)   # marker size
        )
    )

    # Given value x, find a 
    closest_value = df['varA'].iloc[(df['varA'] - slider_input).abs().argsort()[:1]].values[0]
    print(slider_input)
    print(closest_value)
    index_of_x = df.index[df['varA'] == closest_value].tolist()[0]

    corresponding = df.iloc[index_of_x]['varB']

    # Add the dot whose position changes based on the slider input
    fig.add_trace(
        go.Line(
            x=[slider_input],
            y=[corresponding],
            mode='markers',
            marker=dict(color='red', size=12),
            name='Slider Dot'
        )
    )
    return fig


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=False)


This is the output plot. I want the red dot to traverse the blue line according to the slider x value.

Thank you in advance.

If I got that right you are currently looking for the closest value of the pair A and B according to your slider. Then you plot the pair slidervalue and B .. so your plot is doing correct.
I think you want to change the calculation of y (of slider-x) to an interpolation between the existing dots.

Not exactly, I'm hoping for the slider to always be on the blue line (so in the pic above, the plot is wrong because the red dot is not on the blue line). This is a reproducible example that will hopefully enable me to tackle a larger usecase (where the lines are not so straight).

I meant the plot is right because it is doing what you coded..anyway: Add an interpolation based on the closest x values to calculate the corresponding y value to your slider
